# Как локализовать свойства контрола для дизайнера Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, локализация

Имеется проект WinForms на .NET 5, а также класс DataGridViewExt наследуемый от [DataGridView](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview):

```cs
[ComplexBindingProperties("DataSource", "DataMember")]
[DefaultEvent("CellContentClick")]
[DefaultMember("Item")]
[Designer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.DataGridViewDesigner, System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")]
[Docking(DockingBehavior.Ask)]
[Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.DataGridViewComponentEditor, System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(ComponentEditor))]
public class DataGridViewExt : DataGridView
{
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    [Category("Extended properties")]
    public bool DoubleBuffering
    {
        get => DoubleBuffered;
        set => DoubleBuffered = value;
    }
    // конструктор и другие свойства
    // опущены для экономии места
}
```

Свойство [DoubleBuffed](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.doublebuffered) многим знакомо и не нуждается в дополнительном описании, но дело в том, что имеются также свойства, которые не так интуитивны и понятны другим/новым разработчикам. Поэтому было решено использовать атрибут Description с описанием свойства, его зависимостей и т.д.. Так было до тех пор, пока шеф не <del>сошёл с ума</del> решил, что теперь наши контролы должны <del>завоевать мир</del> поддерживать и другие языки. Так как атрибуты [Category](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.categoryattribute) и [Description](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute) не поддерживают локализацию, то был взят атрибут LocalizedDescription, который использовался для описания свойств в [PropertyGrid](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.propertygrid):

```cs
[AttributeUsage(
    AttributeTargets.Property |
    AttributeTargets.Field |
    AttributeTargets.Enum |
    AttributeTargets.Struct, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class LocalizedDescriptionAttribute : DescriptionAttribute
{
    private readonly ResourceManager _resourceManager;
    private readonly string _resourceKey;
    private readonly object[] _formatArgs;
    private string _description;

    public string FormatIfNotFoundKey { get; set; } = "[{0}]";

    public override string Description
    {
        get
        {
            if (_description == null)
            {
                for (var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
                    _description == null && culture != CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                    culture = culture.Parent)
                {
                    string _resourceString = _resourceManager.GetString(_resourceKey);
                    _description = _formatArgs?.Length > 0
                        ? string.Format(_resourceString, _formatArgs)
                        : _resourceString;
                }
            }
            return _description ??= string.Format(FormatIfNotFoundKey, _resourceKey);
        }
    }

    public LocalizedDescriptionAttribute(
        string resourceKey,
        Type resourceType,
        params object[] formatArgs)
        : this(resourceKey, resourceType, null, formatArgs) { }
    public LocalizedDescriptionAttribute(
        string resourceKey,
        ResourceManager resourceManager,
        params object[] formatArgs)
        : this(resourceKey, null, resourceManager, formatArgs) { }
    private LocalizedDescriptionAttribute(
        string resourceKey,
        Type resourceType,
        ResourceManager resourceManager,
        params object[] formatArgs)
    {
        if (resourceKey is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(resourceKey));
        }
        if (resourceType is null && resourceManager is null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                string.Format("{0} and {1} ", nameof(resourceType), nameof(resourceManager)) +
                "cannot be both null at the same time, since we need a resource manager or a type to create it.");
        }

        _resourceKey = resourceKey;
        _resourceManager = resourceManager ?? new ResourceManager(resourceType);
        _formatArgs = formatArgs;
    }
}
```

Но если декорировать этим атрибутом свойство DataGridViewExt, то в дизайнере форм Visual Studio (16.9.0) не отображается ни одно свойство. Смотрел [исходники DataGridView](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/main/src/System.Windows.Forms/src/System/Windows/Forms/DataGridView.cs) на GitHub, но так и не понял каким образом работает используемый [SRDescriptionAttribute](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/main/src/System.Windows.Forms/src/SRDescriptionAttribute.cs). В связи со всем вышенаписанным появился вопрос: каким образом локализовать свойства контролов для дизайнера Visual Studio?

Comment: Я как человек, работающий в компании, где код пилят команды по всему земному шарику, считаю что подобная локализация не нужна. Вполне достаточно документации на английском. А так, посмотрите [это](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/), [это](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/how-to-use-the-xml-documentation-features) и [это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6267658/12888024).

Comment: Ну и в качестве оффтопа. Чему взрослее разраб, тем меньше он использует всякие дизайнеры и тем больше автогенераторы кода на основе шаблонов, в большинстве своём написанных им самим. То есть, по факту подсказки нужны больше в C#, а не в дизайнере, поэтому обычного XMLDoc `///<summary>...` достаточно.

Comment: @aepot я как человек, работающий в компании - человек подневольный. Согласен с Вами, но, как было упомянуто выше, так и работало... До сего момента.

Comment: Ну начать можно с того, что это винформы, остальное - не так страшно. :)

Comment: В `_resourceManager` не находит строку с заданным `_resourceKey`. В итоге `_description` остаётся пустым. | Чтобы проверить это, предлагаю в свойстве `Description` поставить `return "Test";` - появилось описание в PropertyGrid?

Comment: @Alexander_Petrov в случае отсутствия необходимой строки возвращается ключ обёрнутый в квадратные скобки `return _description ??= string.Format(FormatIfNotFoundKey, _resourceKey);`